# Does Asterisk support Group Chat?

Tags: asterisk, xmpp

I am fairly new to Asterisk, I have setup a server with ability to call and instance messaging,

I have done some research about adding Group chat to asterisk but no result yet. Does Asterisk support such features or it should be implemented in another way?

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is PBX.

It even not support usual chat in full.

Sure it support sip message and jabber protocol, but all chat implementation should be on client side.

So no, it not support group chat.

From other point of view - there are nothing preventing relization of group chat,for example, via sip message. Just create dialplan which will maintain group and send message to all members of group.

Comment: @artheops Thank you, for each group there should be a dialplan ? I mean users create group on clients and add their friends, is it possible to create dialplan for such groups dynamically ? and could give me some other hint

I have many question just want to have hints that help me track things in correct way, And other question is, in this case do you suggest to use extra server side chat server ? I mean maybe using sip can not help us, Viber Skype and other use sip server and Xmpp modules for their chat features ?

Comment: Thhat depend of app architector. Yes, it is posible anything, including dynamic dialplan or dialplan which take params. I recommend you use jabberd and jabber connection/chat.